# jquery add to an array on click?

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

I'm confused regarding each() and .each()... I think I need to use both, but I'm not sure how...

Basically, I have a series of checkboxes and when they're checked, I want to get the id of the closest table row and add it to an array that I can then serialize and pass to a function.

So, the html looks like this:

```
<tr id="t1"><td><input type="checkbox" name="did[]" value="232" class="bd" /></td></tr>
<tr id="t2"><td><input type="checkbox" name="did[]" value="234" class="bd" /></td></tr>
<tr id="t3"><td><input type="checkbox" name="did[]" value="676" class="bd" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><button id="tsid" name="tsid" type="button">Send</button></td></tr>
```

And, when (and if) the checkbox is selected, I want to get the closest tr id and store it in an array:

```
var trids = []
```

And then serialize the input data and the trids array...

So far, I only have this:

```
$('#tsid').click(function() {

  //meant to get the values of the selected checkboxes
  var myData = $('input[name=did[]]').serialize();

  //meant to find and store the closest tr ids in an array... 
  $('.bd').each(function() {
    var trids = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);  //and now I'm lost... 
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be:

```
$('.bd:checked').each(function() {
   trids.push($(this).closest("tr").attr('id')); // instead of var trids = ....
});
```

`$('.bd:checked')` selects only the checked checkboxes. 
`closest('tr')` gets the parent `tr` as you already did it correctly. `attr('id')` gets the `id` of this `tr`. There is no need in `get(0)` as `closest()` already selects just one element.
Then this value is added to the array `trids` by using the `push()` method on the array.

**Update:**
jQuery's `.searialize()` function generates a string out of the values of form elements, e.g.:

```
field1=value1&field2=value2&...
```

I don't think it works on arrays though. The only solution I know would be generate the string for the array by yourself:

```
var myData = $('input[name=did[]]').serialize();

for(var i = 0; i < trids.length; i++) {
    myData += '&trid[]=' + trids[i]; or // '&trid%5B%5D=' have it encoded.
}
```

This would append the array values to the serialized string.
But I guess there is a better solution for this.

Comment: Ohhhhhh.... Thanks for this.  How do I get the trids array and the myData array into one?  

I tried var sData = $('input[name=dsid[]]').trids.serialize(); but, obviously... that didn't work...

Comment: @KittyYoung: That depends on how you want to have the resulting array look like.

Comment: Hmm... Not entirely sure I understand what you're asking.  In the end, I want to serialize them both and send it to php.  So, I guess the data would look like: dsid%5B%5D=5&dsid%5B%5D=6&trs%5B%5D=t1

Is that what you mean?

Comment: @KittyYoung: Not exactly but my comment was unnecessary due the fact that you want to serialize the data and `serialize()` only works on form element. See updated answer whether this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the elements, then use the `map` function to get the id from each tr element. Use the `get` method to get the result as an array instead of an jQuery object.

```
var trids = $('.bd').map(function(i,e){ return $(e).closest('tr').attr('id'); }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var checkbox_values= [];
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $(this).each(function(){
                var checked_value = $(this).val();
                checkbox_values.push(checked_value);
            });
            console.log( "checked_value: " + checkbox_values);
           //output checked_value: 232
           //output checked_value: 232,234
           //output checked_value: 232,234,676
        } else {
            console.log('not checked');
        }    
      });
    });
```